# implementing push notifications in android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

Hello everyone i am trying to implement push notifications with urbanairship

i followed the steps from http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=235

but got this error:

```
   03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at com.nano.push.PushPreferencesActivity.<init>(PushPreferencesActivity.java:58)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
03-30 16:10:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(13171):    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their applications on Android devices. The service provides a simple, lightweight mechanism that servers can use to tell mobile applications to contact the server directly, to fetch updated application or user data. The C2DM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target application running on the target device.

So how do you go about setting up C2DM push notifications in your Android app from your web application? Here are the steps to follow for both the Android app and Web server.
Signing up for C2DM

The first step is to signup at http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html. Fill in the relevant information, the most important being the package name of your app and Role account email. This is the email id you will use to setup and run C2DM notifications. It has to be a valid gmail account. Make sure you don’t use this email id on any device. Once you finish signing up, you have to wait to receive a confirmation email from Google that your registration has been accepted.
Things needed to do on the Android front
After you’ve registered, you have to make your android app C2DM enabled. Your app on a device needs to register with Google’s C2DM server for receiving messages. This requires quite a bit of plumbing code. The classes from Google’s C2DM sample project ChromeToPhone can be used as a base and expanded on if required.

the following link that i have used will be helpful for you.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

this is a very good link for push how to use push notification.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

may be your project need dependent libraries, you can try it:

1. right click your project and select project property
2. enter "java build path"->"order and export"
3. select all your project compiled need dependent projects